How can I in retrospect find the cause of a slow disk write?
At 18.57 October 2 a program that runs on Windows 11 that writes large amounts of data continously to file on a SSD started writing significantly slower than normal to the disk.
How can I investigate this and find what caused this problem?
So far I have identified these two possible reasons:

realtime virus scan
windows update

From my understanding running Get-MpComputerStatus in powershell should report back the last time a virus scan was done?
Further running Get-HotFix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn -Descending in powershell should report back the last time a windows update was performed?
Are there logs showing which processes used disk IO and CPU as a function of time that I can access from the PC?

the fact that you said "on a SSD" suggests you have more than one disk ... is this SSD only used by that one program?

Do you know what the file name was?

You could obviously look for any newly created or modified files
within those dates that might give a clue, particularly in the temp
folders under %appdata% and any text files
You could look at the plethora of event logs under the "applications
and services" selection in event viewer. I doubt there is anything
of use but you never know
You could look at task scheduler and see if there are any that could
have triggered at that time (think that is probably another
thankless task)

The tools I know (perfmon, process monitor etc) are not retrospective unfortunately.  Hope that helps although suspect not much.
Other very niche thought came to mind - Windows has decided to increase the pagefile. Doubt that would cause the effects you've described though
